# How do you find the maximum and minimum for a random array?

Tags: java

```
   public class ArrayCalculations
   {
      public static void main(String[]  args)
      {

         int sum = 0, smallest, largest;
         double average;
         int[] array = new int[20];

         for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
         {

            array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 500 + 1);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            sum += array[i];
            smallest = array[0];
            largest = array[];
            if(array[i]<smallest)
            {
               smallest = array[i];
            }
            if(array[i]>largest)
            {
            largest = array[i];
            }

         }
         average = 1.0*sum/array.length;

         System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
         System.out.println("Average: " + average);
         System.out.println("Smallest: " + smallest);
         System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
      }
   }
```

It keeps saying that smallest and largest may not have been initialized. I am not sure how to fix it. I tried setting smallest and largest to the first number outside of the for loop but that was before the all the numbers in the array were initialized so that didn't work...

Comment: It looks like you were writing some java and then started following a javascript manual half way through `Math.random` is a javascript function but `System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);` looks like java

Comment: @andrew:  `Math.random` exists in Java too.

Comment: @Makoto, ok, thanks, I did google for it but didn't find it, its quite some time since i used java

Answer (score 3):

You're basically resetting the values of `smallest` and `largest` to the first element in the for loop (considering `largest = array[]` is a typing error).

Yes you need to initialize them outside the loop.

```
smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 500 + 1);
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    sum += array[i];
    if(array[i] < smallest) smallest = array[i];
    if(array[i] > largest)  largest = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

- Inside of a method (like `main`), you ***cannot*** leave variables uninitialized that you intend to use later.  The reason that Java isn't initializing those variables is due to the possibility of skipping the loop; even though it's unlikely in this scenario, Java believes that it's still a possibility.
- The largest value you've ever seen in that list is negative infinity, and the smallest value that you've ever seen in that list is infinity (that is, you don't know exactly where it may lurk).  Initialize those two variables to the smallest and largest value you can.

  ```
  int sum = 0, smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE, largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  ```

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer, but I think that it makes more sense to initialize the variables to `null`, and check for `null` before printing the values out.

Comment: @Rainbolt:  You can't initialize a primitive to `null`.  Are you thinking about `Integer` instead?  Or do you think that they *really* should be treated as an array?  Also, how would `null` help even *if* they were `Integer`?  What numeric value does it hold? ;)

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Any sentinel value outside the bounds of what his random generator can produce would work (for example, -1 would work fine, because it looks like his generator only produces 0 through 500). I don't know why you are asking what numeric value `null` holds. Null doesn't have a numeric value...

Answer (score 1):

```
        largest = array[];
                  ^^^^^^^
```

Why are you making `largest` an array, then trying to treat it as a simple integer?

```
        if(array[i]>largest)
           ^^^^^^^^----integer
                    ^^^^^^^---array
```

A better structure would be

```
array[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 500 + 1);
      ^---note 0 index
largest = array[0];
smallest = array[0];

for(i = 1; ...) {
        ^--start at index #1
   array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 500 + 1);
   if (array[i] < smallest) {
     smallest = array[i];
   }
   if (array[i] > largest) {
     largest = array[i];
  }
}
```

Basically, do the initialization OUTSIDE the loop.